# Deploying war with bitbucket pipeline

Tags: tomcat, grails, bitbucket, war, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm trying to deploy my war application written using Grails framework with pipeline in Bitbucket.
My pipeline so far is this:

```
image: redwolfgang20/grails:latest

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: Clean a build grails war
        script:
          - grails prod war
```

This works, it pulls the code and compile the application, and I get the war file.
Now I have to push it to a remote tomcat server. I can use SFTP and copy it under webapp/ folder, but I'd like to use manager application inside tomcat so that I can get a proper response and know if the application has been deploied correctly. Unfortunately the manager application is not public, my server has nginx server as proxy for tomcat showing only 443 and 22 ports.
I was thinking to use a SSH tunneling to access to localhost:8080 but not so sure how to do it in pipeline. Maybe there is a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you have NginX-->Tomcat, then you can still access Tomcat Manager through NginX, right? Then you can do this via Tomcat Manager app and some simple curl requests, see [this question for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19276753/how-can-i-deploy-a-web-application-to-tomcat-application-server-via-terminal-com)